# How to draw a grid size n x m in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

It is seem to be newbie question. But I don't know how to generate the N x M grid in draw.io

My current solution for 3x3 grid:

Step 1. Draw 9 squares

[image: 9 squares]

Step 2. Drag-and-drop them into grid formation.

[image]

However, this method does not scale very well. If I want to draw 9x9 grid, it is take a lot of time.

Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, draw.io doesn't support that but feel free to vote and track this feature request here:
https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/677

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

If draw.io doesn't support it, at least don't let it scale it quadratically, but scale it linearly.

If you want a 9x9, create 9 squares on a row, select all and copy, then paste the row 8 times. That is 18 actions instead of 81.